# Case Insensitive Search on Git log comments

Tags: git, less, case-insensitive, git-log

I use 'git log' and search for any comments by backslash / and typing the search text.
Using this I cannot do case insensitive search. For example vi we can use ':set ic' and do the search. But in 'git log' it is always case sensitive. Which make it difficult to find the relevant text. People don't always have the same case when writing the commit message.

I can use the grep/sed on command line but it doesn't give the full picture and time consuming to type the regex.

Is there way for searching 'git log' case insensitively?
Found out that git log is not using the vim/vi but similar pager

**Update:**
I used the following command to update the git log search to be always case-insensitive

```
git config core.pager "less -IR -"
```

Comment: How are you doing the git-log searches?

Comment: @Schwern, by default when typed 'git log' it launches vim and there I search / and text. Your solution of using less seems to be in the right direction. Downside is I loose the vim color and formatting which makes it easier to read.

Comment: Then this is really a vim question. That's quite odd that `git log` would launch vim. Did you set your PAGER environment variable?

Comment: You can retain color and formatting while using less by using `-R`. This passes the ANSI color characters through. So `LESS=-iR` would give you case insensitive searches and color.

Comment: According to question and comments OP knows how to do case-insensitive search in Vim *and* uses Vim as pager for `git log` -> the problem does not exist. What am I missing?

Comment: @Friedrich , but when git log opens the vim as pager it is always case-sensitive. No way to turn that into case-insensitive search. Please try it on any linux. Other than  using some other pager which i found out by posting this question

Comment: Tried `git config core.pager "vim -R -"; git log` on Debian. It uses `smartcase` as set in my `vimrc`, i.e. it's case insensitive. Even if it wasn't, you could `:set ic`. There's a flaw somewhere in your assumptions. I don't think your `git log` opens Vim at all.

Comment: @Friedrich, yes i think you are right it is not opening vim/vi. May be the git built-in pager. Tried your method and it works I will update my question

Comment: I think Schwern's answer is as good as it gets for this question. We can let it rest.

Comment: @RamananT "*git uses vim by default*" Git does not use vim as a pager by default, it uses less. Something is odd about your Git configuration. Check `git config --list --show-origin` and the `GIT_PAGER` and `PAGER` environment variables.

Comment: @Schwern, thanks , I was able to find out that after my last comment.  Friedrich comment helped me.  I used this command  ' git config core.pager "less -IR -" '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git log` typically sends its output to a [pager program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager), you can use that to search.

The pager is on probably [`less`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28Unix%29). If so, you can use `-i` or `-I` (they're subtly different) to make less searches ignore case.

You can set the `LESS` environment variable to `-i` or `-I`, then `less` searches are case-insensitive by default everywhere. Or set `core.pager` to `less -i` or `less -I` so only it is only case-insensitive with Git.

See [the Git config value core.pager](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corepager) and [the less manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html) for more.

Comment: I think this is the best way forward for this question.

Comment: According to `git help config` (the page you link to), git uses `LESS=FRX` if `LESS` is unset. IMHO the best way seems to be to set `core.pager` to `less -i` to have case-insensitivity for git and only git while keeping the defaults.

Comment: @Friedrich I didn't realize that! Still, setting LESS fixes color for every program. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In `man git-log`:

> -i, --regexp-ignore-case
> Match the regular expression limiting patterns without regard to letter case.

Comment: Actually this doesn't work for my case.

Comment: What is the command and regex you use?

Comment: Give a real example then. Input commits messages and what are you trying to match. Please edit your original post

Comment: on Linux (specifically RedHat 8) if you type git log under git cloned directory it opens it in vim pager. you can search using / and text. where i need case-insensitive search.